# MySQL: select rows until a smaller number is reached

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a stored procedure where I need to display the most books that are checked out at any given time. For example, I can generate the following with the data in my table:

```
callNumber          title                NumberCheckedOut
    1             Unbroken                      2
    2             Outliers                      2
    3         Intro to CompSci                  2
    4       One World School House              1
    5          DB For Dummies                   1
```

For this example, I only want to display Unbroken, Outliers, and Intro to CompSci since these books are the books with the most copies checked out.

The code used to generated this stored procedure is:

```
BEGIN

SELECT Book.callNumber, Book.title, Count(Book.callNumber) AS NumCheckedOut
FROM Book, Borrows, Copy
WHERE (Book.callNumber = Borrows.callNumber) AND (Copy.copyNumber = Borrows.copyNumber) AND (Book.callNumber = Copy.callNumber)
GROUP BY Book.callNumber 
ORDER BY Book.callNumber;

END
```

What change(s) can I make to this stored procedure to only select the books with the maximum number of copies checked out?

Comment: `HAVING NumberCheckedOut = max(NumberCheckedOut)`

Comment: You should clean up your query to use explicit joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  I don't believe you need the `copy` table for the query:

```
SELECT b.callNumber, b.title, Count(*) AS NumCheckedOut
FROM Book b JOIN
     Borrows bor
     ON b.callNumber = bor.callNumber
GROUP BY b.callNumber 
ORDER BY b.callNumber;
```

Then, you only need `Book` to get the additional information.

You can do the filtering with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT b.callNumber, b.title, Count(*) AS NumCheckedOut
FROM Book b JOIN
     Borrows bor
     ON b.callNumber = bor.callNumber
GROUP BY b.callNumber 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM Borrows
                   GROUP BY callNumber
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  )
ORDER BY b.callNumber;
```